# \overline across array columns, maintaining alignment

Tags: arrays, columns, overline

As a concrete example of something I often want, here's a snippet that has array column separators inside an `\overline` (to use [overline notation](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6.945/readings/Steele-MIT-April-2017.pdf#page=51) to denote multiple inequalities):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{lcr}
1 & < & 3 \\
\overline{2222 & < & 4} \\ % Comment this line out and it compiles.
3 & < & 5 \\
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, that gives an error and in general does so for many if not all macros other than `overline`.

Is there are a way to get an `overline` over the second equation that maintains the alignment of = across all array lines?

If there is, would that approach work for other, user-defined macros, too?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `\hline`?

Comment: I don't think I am. The line should extend exactly above the `2222 < 4` expression.

Comment: Probably a real use case would be better.

Comment: The use case is overline notation https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6.945/readings/Steele-MIT-April-2017.pdf#page=51 to denote multiple constraints of the form `a_1 ⊑ b_1` ... `a_n ⊑ b_n`. The ⊑ should align with the ⊑ on other lines of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious to know what the meaning would be, but here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l @{}}
1 & < & 3 \\
\overline{2222} & \overline{{\vphantom{22224}}<{}} & \overline{4} \\
3 & < & 5
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the real use case you may need other `\vphantom` commands.

Comment: Nice, tanks. I added a comment on the OP and updated the question with a link that describes overline notation to give motivation for the real use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to `amsmath` style alignments with `align*` and friends and use LuaLaTeX, then you can use my `luamathalign` package which provides a `\AlignHere` command, It which works like `&` but is allowed pretty much everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,luamathalign}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
1 & < 3 \\
\overline{2222 \AlignHere < 4} \\
3 & < 5 \\
3 & < 55
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer if lualatex is an option. It isn't for me, so the hack from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656131/52414 is my preferred answer.